# How to set the font for symbols?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, math-fonts

Epsilon font is completely different from other font. it need to same link other fonts.

Here is following tex that i render pdf using xelatex.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[hiresbb]{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=324pt, margin=10pt]{geometry}

\newcommand{\lt}{<}
\newcommand{\hyphen}{\hyp}
\newcommand{\gt}{>}

\setmainfont[
     Path = /var/www/html/_default/DeployCode/jagan/common/cms/v2.0/fonts/MinionPro/,
     Extension  = .otf,
     Ligatures  = TeX,
     BoldFont   = MinionProBold,
     ItalicFont = MinionProItalic,
     BoldItalicFont = MinionProBoldItalic
]{MinionProRegular}

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newlength{\mydepth}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

    \fontsize{12pt}{13.5pt}\selectfont
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}$Q = CV = A{\varepsilon} {\varepsilon _0}\dfrac{V\alpha}{d}$\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\settowidth {\mywidth}  {\usebox{\mybox}}
\settoheight{\myheight} {\usebox{\mybox}}
\settodepth {\mydepth}  {\usebox{\mybox}}

\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname.sizes
    \immediate\write\foo{"Depth" : "\the\mydepth",}
    \immediate\write\foo{"Height" : "\the\myheight",}
    \addtolength{\myheight} {\mydepth}
    \immediate\write\foo{"TotalHeight" : "\the\myheight",}
    \immediate\write\foo{"Width" : "\the\mywidth"}
\closeout\foo

\begin{document}
    \color[RGB]{0, 0, 0}
    \pagecolor[RGB]{255, 255, 255}
    \usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you have been here for more than a year. I also see that over the course of time you have asked a few question(s) and received answer(s). But unfortunately, none of them being accepted. So, before asking a new question, if you find them useful, could you kindly accept them?

Comment: That's `\varepsilon` as rendered in Asana Math. I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Sorry! egreg small mistake in tex code. i modified that now. epsilon symbols is rendered as some other font not as minion pro. that's my problem.